# how can i reduce the size of image in imageview

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. what i am doing is displaying 20 images as grid and selected image is diaplyed as full image in imageview. when i rotate the simulator to landscape image is not adjusted correctly in image view. i am trying by changing  the position of image but no use. now what i need  is reduce the size of selected image size in landscape mode how can i done this pls help me. thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're setting up the new frame of your image view correctly, try this:

```
[anImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```